# I can only access the terminal

Tags: nvidia, system

I installed Ubuntu. Now every time I reboot I get `/dev/sda2: clean`. Some answers say I'll need to purge nvidia drivers.

This was the suggestion I saw: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04

However I am looking for some other way to solve the issue.

Comment: My work PC which had Nvidia drivers from an older Lubuntu installation worked fine after upgrading to 20.04, but a few days ago, after an automatic update and a reboot, X did not start anymore. Long story short, remove the nvidia drivers.

Comment: Some details may help, are you using 18.04?  Are you cleanly shutting the system down (SysRq keys, login via terminal etc) or forcing power off (thus the `fsck` messages are to be expected). Did you just install? or it's an install that went wrong as asked because of your changes? upgrades? or anything else (such as you installing different Nvidia drivers?)

Comment: I am using the 20.04. I switched to Ubuntu two weeks ago and a couple of days later this happened. The graphics processor is Nvidia GeForce 930M and I have made no changes to it. I always shut the system from the terminal.

Comment: I purged my system of Nvidia drivers. Now the system works just fine. Thank you for your suggestion Erich Kitzmueller.